# FFmpeg + JWplayer + Mp4 fails

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, jwplayer6

Im using `JWplayer` HTML5 6.5.3609, and the newest `FFmpeg`. This is how I set it up:

```
jwplayer("flowplayer1").setup({
    file: '/mp4.file.place'
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    autostart: true,
    stretching: 'exactfit',
    ratio: "100%",
    responsive: true,
    primary: 'html5'
});
```

this is a direct access, if I call the MP4 file directly, browser can play it. I create this MP4 from standalone images:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 1 -i img%d.png x.mp4
```

and no joy. I even tried to add some codecs:

```
-vcodec libx264 -acodec libfaac
```

still not work, I got this:

```
error loading media: file could not be played
```

the joke is, I tried it with FLV and it did worked... VLC player can play the MP4 file too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, thanks for the helps ( :) ) in the meantime I figured it out, I simply had to ad the

**-pix_fmt yuv420p**

parameter.

Comment: You should also add `-movflags +faststart` so the video can begin playback before it is completely downloaded by the client.

Comment: yes-yes, Ive figured it out about an hour ago :) now the only thing is, on firefox+smartphone it kills the firefox (but firefox on Win7 works well)